# Get the latest timestamp from a set of files based on first line in a file

Tags: shell-script, files, date

### Each day I get 16 files in a path `/Home/h87654/file/`. The first line of every file  will have a string containing that day’s date  (YYYYMMDD).  The position of date is not fixed, it can be anywhere on the first line.i want to get the latest file arrived  each day based on the  date  on first line .

apologies  for question being too broad.

am new to  unix . below is the code i am working on .

/Home/h87654/latest_file.txt  this will have all  the 16 files having respective date in first line.
out of those 16 , i need  to get the latest file  with timestamp 
for ex: 
if we are running the script today ,ie 2018-06-11 . start date would be 20180501 and end_date would be 20180531
in first loop , latest_file.txt will have  all files containing 20180501 in first line. i need the file  which came the last  and its timestamp and write both to time.txt

secod loop , latest_file.txt will have  all files containing 20180502 in first line,i need the file  which came the last   and its timestamp and append both to time.txt

thrid  loop,latest_file.txt will have  all files containing 20180503 in first line,i need the file  which came the last   and its timestamp and appendboth to time.txtand so on till the month end . $end_date

```
cd /Home/h87654/file/
start_date=`date -d "-1 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +%Y%m%d` ##start of month in  yyyymmdd
end_date=`date -d "-$(date +%d) days " +%Y%m%d` ##end of month in  yyyymmdd

while [ "$start_date" > "$end_date" ]; ##execute for each day for a  monnth

do
awk 'FNR==1{if($0~"$start_date")print FILENAME;}'  /Home/h87654/file/*.* >/Home/h87654/latest_file.txt   ##check ist date in the first line and print the file name 
##am stuck here .. idk how to proceed 


done
```

Comment: This is not a order-my-script forum. Please detail what you have done until now, your questions, and how we might be able to help you.

Comment: This is unclear.  You get 16 files per day?  Do all files have today's date in them?  If so how do you determine the last file? What determines the date offsets of your "loops"?  You mention it should start with 20180214 and then move onto 20180202, should it check for every 12 days or is there some other factor determining that?

Comment: Hi Jesse_b , 

apologies for the insufficient content. now to your  question ,
1.yes i get  16 files per day .few files might get late  and receive it next day too.
2.yes .all 16 files will have same date .yyyymmdd
3. i need to deteremine the last file  based on the timstamp.
4. i need to  run the loop  everyday for one month  .

Comment: Advice: [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163), it can significantly popularize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking exactly.

To get the path of a file with the greatest first sequence of 8 digits in their first line, with `zsh`:

```
getdate() {
  local MATCH
  IFS= read -r < $REPLY && [[ $REPLY =~ '[[:digit:]]{8}' ]]
  REPLY=$MATCH
}

printf '%s\n' /Home/h87654/file/*.*(O+getdate[1])
```

To get the greatest date and all the files that contain that greatest date as the first sequence of 8 digits in their first line, you could do something like:

```
typeset -A bydate
for file (/Home/h87654/file/*.*) {
  IFS= read -r line < $file &&
    [[ $line =~ '[[:digit:]]{8]' ]] &&
    bydate[$MATCH]+=$file$'\n'
}
latest=${${(kO)bydate}[1]}
printf 'Latest date: %s\nFiles:\n%s' $latest $bydate[$latest]
```